# Using merge in Power Query while keeping native query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm trying to reduce my dataset of 1.000.000 records to only the subset I need (+/- 500) by creating an Inner Join to a different table. Unfortunataly it seems that Power Query drops the "native query" and loads the entire dataset before reducing it by merging it with a related table. I have no access to the database unfortunately, otherwise I would have written the SQL myself. Is there a way to make merge work with a native SQL query?

Thanks

Comment: [Edit] your question to show your query code

Comment: If you need it to be a native query, one option is to put a SQL query inside of your connection string as explained [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-data-from-database-using-native-database-query-power-query-f4f448ac-70d5-445b-a6ba-302db47a1b00). I don't know that this will work if you don't have execution privileges on the database though.

Answer (score 1):

I would first check that your "related table" query can run as a native query - right-click on it's last step and check if **View Native Query** is enabled.

If that's the case, then it may be due to the **Join Kind** in the **Merge Queries** step. I've noticed that against SQL Server data sources, Join Kinds other than the default **Left Outer Join** tend to kill the Native Query option.

Comment: I’m trying to do an inner join. Isn’t that supported by Power Query? Seems like a pretty straightforward and standard SQL join right? My source table and target table are both showing native query up to the point in trying to merge. Seems it’s not supported :(

Comment: Yes its frustrating. I've raised it as an issue - please comment and vote. https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/Power-Query-on-SQL-Merge-Queries-Inner-Join-breaks-Native-Query/idi-p/563692